# How to overlay parent element with rgba and also overlay child images

Tags: html, css

```css
#parent{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
}

img{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div>I am text</div>
<div>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/>
</div>
<div>
```

As you can see, the image is not gettin overlaid although its parent has rgba opacity set. However, I would like the images to have same overlay as the parent. How do I overcome this? (I need IE 10, 11 compatibility)

Comment: The parent doesn’t have an actual `opacity` set, it only has a background color. Would you change color, if I just painted the wall behind you …?

Comment: You can set `z-index: -1` to the image, though I don't know if it is cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this below css:

```css
    #parent::before{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
#parent{
    position: relative;
}

img{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <div id="parent">
                <div>I am text</div>
                <div>
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```css
img{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div>I am text</div>
  <div class="image">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/>
  </div>
<div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tscbgo9j/)

Comment: this is very good but I had to change several images if I take this method. I upvote it instead of accepting.